# How to check whether a symbolic expression is rational?

Tags: sympy

I'm using [Sympy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) and I haven't found a simple way of testing for *x ∈ **Q***.

*Context:* I have a set of solutions of a set of very simple, 2DoF eigenvalue problems (e.g.,

[image]

) and I want to check if one of these solutions is rational (or, in other words, if the solution doesn't contains a square root).

A direct way of checking is what I would like the best, but I could accept also an answer that deals with finding (not finding) a square root in the solution.

Comment: What sort of return types do you get (some code might be helpful)? If they're floating-point numbers rather than some Sympy numeric class, it'll be difficult to decide this as [all floats are rational numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266844/4316405).

Comment: @N.Wouda In the title of my question I explicitly ask about **expressions**.  —  I'm using Sympy, my solutions are lists of (two) symbolic expressions, we are not dealing with floats as in [all floats are rational numbers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4266844/4316405).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `rational = lambda x: all(i.exp.is_Integer for i in x.atoms(Pow))` is a direct translation of your criteria to return True if all powers (if present) are integers.

```
>>> from sympy import Pow, S, sqrt
>>> rational = lambda x: all(i.exp.is_Integer for i in x.atoms(Pow))
>>> rational(S.Half)
True
>>> rational(sqrt(3))
False
>>> rational(3/(1+sqrt(3)))
False
```