# Determine x/y fraction has repeating decimal expansion

Tags: math, fractions

Is there any quick method to determine that x/y fraction based only on integers giving in result repeating part in the end? Thank you.

```
def repeatless(x, y):
    // some code here...
    return True
```

Comment: What values are you imagining that `x` or `y` might have, such that their ratio isn't a rational number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if a number is rational in Python, for a given fp accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4266741/check-if-a-number-is-rational-in-python-for-a-given-fp-accuracy)

Comment: If x and y are integers then x/y is always rational and you can always return true without doing any other code at all. Maybe what you're actually interested in is whether the decimal representation is finite or has a repeating part.

Comment: sorry, made a mistake while describing problem. im looking for multi-language language solution for two integers input

Comment: @nesclass Quoting [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number) **In mathematics, a rational number is a number such as −3/7 that can be expressed as the quotient or fraction p/q of two integers, a numerator p and a non-zero denominator q.** If `x` and `y` are integers as you say the question makes no sense, that's the definition.

Comment: @Patrick87 corrected me, but im not completely sure about his vision to this question. Here, i mean that fraction 2/3 is being irrational, because producing it gives 0.(6)

Comment: @nesclass I will post an answer based on this update and then edit your question to reflect your true intent: an algorithm to say whether the fraction x/y has a repeating decimal expansion

Comment: Thank you, ive got where i was wrong about this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given integers x and y, the fraction x/y has a repeating decimal expansion if and only if:

1. y / gcd(x, y) has factors other than 2 and 5, and
2. the remainder after dividing x by y is not zero

NOTE: as pointed out in the comments, my original answer had a flaw in that it only worked if x/y was an irreducible fraction (in lowest terms). This is remedied by first dividing y by gcd(x, y) so that you're checking whether the denominator of the equivalent irreducible fraction has factors other than powers of 2 and 5.

The second condition is pretty easy to check:

```
HasRepeatingDecimal(x, y)
1. if x % y == 0 then return false
```

Now we need to see if y / gcd(x, y) has factors other than 2 and 5. We can do this by repeatedly dividing y / gcd(x, y) by 5 and then by 2 and see if we end up with the number 1:

```
HasRepeatingDecimal(x, y)
1. if x % y == 0 then return false
2. y = y / gcd(x, y)
3. while (y % 5 == 0) y = y / 5
4. while (y % 2 == 0) y = y / 2
5. if y == 1 then return true else return false
```

The reason you can check the denominator's divisibility by 2 and 5 is that the decimal system has base 10 and 2 and 5 are the only prime factors of 10. If you were using base-21, you'd check for y / gcd(x, y) being of the form 3^a x 7^b instead.

Comment: That's pretty good solution, but in the best case im looking for non-while function, like any mathematical property that can be used here.

Comment: @nesclass The mathematical property is "y is of the form 2^a * 5^b for nonnegative integers a and b"... repeatedly dividing is the first way of checking that which came to mind, but perhaps there are other ways?

Comment: @MarkDickinson Good catch, you're absolutely right. Let me update the answer.